# how can i do this simple entity relationship diagram?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, database-normalization

i'm needing help to build an entity relationship diagram efficiently for a project. This is the most important part of my problem:

There are organizations, which can have many challenges inside like for example: they are very small and is very uncomfortable for the employees to work there, they have very old resources to work with, etc.

On the other hand, this challenges can have many ideas to solve them. This ideas can be published by regular clients and employees of the organization too. Also, the idea can be evaluated by many employees of type evaluator. This employees (normal type) belong to an specific organization, except for the type evaluator which can be in many, so i can evaluate many ideas from different org.

So my problem is... in the current version of the diagram, the team related a table user to employees and clients (both tables), this way the user is the one that publishes and idea and then we can see at it's type to check in what table the information is (client or employee). But an idea can have many evaluations, and they have to be done by one or many employees of type evaluator. So an user publish an idea, and an user evaluates and idea? i mean, is enough in the diagram just to specify the relationship between user and idea? do i need to show the relationship user and evaluation to? and if that's so, isn't that like strange in the diagram?

On the other side, i see a bit of recurrence too in the part where they relate organizations with employee, employee with user, user with idea, organization with challenges, challenges with idea. Is that ok in a ERM diagrama?

I just need a little explanation of why you can or cannot do it this way. I'm a bit confused.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to visualize your diagram from the description. Can you upload an image for us?

Comment: Yeah i know... sorry. I only have images in spanish, i don't think that would be helpful.

Comment: I believe it would be helpful. If Intern87's answer isn't sufficient, feel free to upload your spanish image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are creating an ideas management system.

a quick search on google for ['"idea management" entity relationship diagram'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22idea+management%22+entity+relationship+diagram&espv=2&biw=1372&bih=634&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrw-PB2bnQAhWBcCYKHQ6yAfcQsAQIGg#imgrc=c3-AIQKuG9nrKM%3A) brought this up, which seems quite close to your mark;
[image: entity relationship diagram]

Also, just append the table Company to user and project.